# Find all the irreducible representations of the group

Tags: representation-theory

I want to find all irreducible representations of $\{ 
     \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right];a\in\mathbb{F}^\times_p,b\in\mathbb{F}_p
\}$. My approach was to use the fact that this group can be expressed as semi-direct product, but it gets complicated and I don't know how to proceed after that. Is there any simpler way of solving this? Can I somehow use the character of this matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a surjective map from the group to $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$.  This latter group is cyclic of order $p-1$, so it has $p-1$ characters ($1$-dimensional). Composed with the projection gives us $p-1$ $1$-dimensional representations of $G$.

Now, the order of the group is $p(p-1)$. The formula for the sum of squares of dimensions suggests there should be another $p-1$ irreducible representation.

Note that $G$ acts naturally on $\mathbb{F}_p$, so on the complex valued functions on $\mathbb{F}_p$.  This representation has a $1$ dimensional subrepresentation, the space of constant functions. There is a complement, the space of functions with sum of values $0$. This will be the missing irreducible representation.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have trouble following the first paragraph. There seems to be a subgroup $C_{p-1}$, namely $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ and this has $p-1$ 1-dimensional irreducibles. Are we lifting this to the representation of the original group?

Comment: Note that you cannot in general  lift representations from a subgroup to a group. The fact is that there is a map $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right] \mapsto a$ that is a surjective morphism. Now you can get from representations of the quotient group to representations of the group.

Comment: Oh got it. How do we know that the action of $\mathbb{F}_p$ on the polynomials whose sum of values $0$ is irreducible?

Comment: @able20: if it were not irreducible, it would have to be the sum of some other irreducibles, and since the possible dimensions are $1$ and $p-1$, it should be a sum of $1$-dim. ones. But it is easy to check that any $1$ dim subrepresentation of the space of functions on $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the space of constant functions. So the complement has not subreps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused now. What do you mean by "act naturally"?

Comment: @able20: The action of $G$ on $\mathbb{F}_p$ is $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right] \cdot x = a x + b$. It is like multiplying  the vector $(x,1)^t$ with the matrix .